# How Fortigate 100D send log to Splunk

Tags: network-monitoring, splunk

I have a Fortigate 100D with FortiOS 5.06 , this is my setting

```
config log syslogd setting
set status enable
set server “192.168.7.4″
set reliable disable
set port 515
set csv disable
set facility alert
set source-ip 192.168.9.2
end
```

I have a Splunk server 192.168.7.4 listening on port 515 TCP, my switches can forward their logs to Splunk normally, but I cannot get Fortigate to work. Splunk server doesn’t receive any logs from Fortigate.

Answer (score 2):

Set `reliable disable = UDP`, you need to set `reliable enable = tcp`

From fortinet CLI handbook:

> reliable {disable | enable} Enable reliable delivery of syslog
>   messages to the syslog server. When enabled, the FortiGate unit
>   implements the RAW profile of RFC 3195, sending log messages using TCP
>   protocol.

Comment: Hi, welcome do SF. It is not at at all clear what you are asking. Please reword your question and perhaps supply more context.

Answer (score 0):

Syslog is usually UDP 514, and Splunk certain works fine when set to use this.

Comment: Hi Chopper3, I configure Splunk to open and listen on port 515 TCP, other my Cisco Switchs work ok with that.